# Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS System Tray Icons not all showing

Tags: 18.04, icons, system-tray, budgie

I don't know if this has been solved or not, and I didn't see it.  I'm a complete noob to Ubuntu Budgie and I have 18.04 LTS with the latest updates.

I have Dropbox, Mega, and a few other things installed that are not showing in the System Tray at any point.  Dropbox did for a little bit, but then it's gone.  Mega, Thunderbird, qBittorrent, don't show up at all.  pCloud and Skype show up right now, also when I turn on Franz it shows up.

Can someone please help? I'm sure this has been solved before but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: on simple Ubuntu 18.04.1 I just logged out and switched to `Ubuntu on Wayland` and than everything worked as expected in tray. Maybe this helps someone else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This problem is common for both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

The reason of issue is lack of the `libgtk2-appindicator-perl` package in main Ubuntu 18.04 repository. A workaround is to install `libappindicator-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libappindicator-dev
```

and `Gtk2::AppIndicator` perl extension:

```
sudo cpan -i Gtk2::AppIndicator
```

Restart your applications, now all of missing icons have to appear in system tray.

Comment: Here is the ubuntu bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/1768032

Comment: This solved the problem once but the icons disappeared after rebooting.

Comment: it does not work for me. Neither the dropbox, nor the variety's icon appeared in the system tray. I tested it with Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 9 with same result.

Comment: It does not work on Linux Mint 19.1 issue :(

Comment: Wow, couple of commands that started half an hour rebuilding of something... and don't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the bug in Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/+bug/1795121

It says 18.10, but I see exactly the same thing in 18.04. The workaround described in this works: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (restarting the window manager).

An update to this: the issue was fixed and the fix released a while ago now. I haven't had the issue reoccur since.

Comment: What's that command prompt that `Alt+F2` brings up?

Comment: This worked, and didn't require a reboot like the accepted solution.

Comment: @jayarjo it's literally a command prompt. You can type commands in it (and a couple of secret shortcuts like 'r'.)

Answer (score 7):

Using budgie settings ensure you have the appindicator applet added to your panel.

A few applications show their panel icons as application indicator and not as a traditional system tray icon.

Comment: Aw snap! I thought the system indicator IS the app indicator!

Answer (score 2):

(I could not comment @fossfreedom's answer)

His tip solved the issue for me, but I had to install a package manually before. So, **if you are using "vanilla" Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10 with Budgie Desktop**, assert that the AppIndicator Applet is installed. If not:

1. Install the package `budgie-indicator-applet`
2. **Restart the session**
3. Add the AppIndicator Applet to the panel (preferably, right next to System Tray)

If you have any open application that uses it (ex.: Dropbox), the icon should show up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

- Install app-indicator using `sudo apt install budgie-indicator-applet`
- Logout/Login
- Launch budgie desktop settings from terminal:

  ```
  $ budgie-desktop-settings
  ```

  This settings manager is inside of budgie-desktop package. You could find all related packages by invoking a command:

  ```
  $ apt-cache search budgie-desktop
  ```
- Add applet go to Top Panel section, click the Add applet 'plus' button and choose what you need.

  [image: Bugie Desktop Settings applet adding to panel picture]

  [image]

If that did not help, you could also try

- `sudo apt install libappindicator-dev` as someone already suggested
- Log out and Log in again to see if you have this applet available in **Budgie Desktop Settings**

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

solved the issue