# Overgrive tray icon is not displayed

Tags: 18.04, system-tray, google-drive, grive

I've been using Overgrive for a while and suddenly I realized that in some point the tray icon stopped being loaded. I don't know when and why. However, Overgrive is running and apparently working (files seem to be synced with my Drive) and if I try to loaded manually I get:

```
maramirez@maramirez-laptop:~$ python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive
overGrive instance already running
```

Usually, I had two tray icons: Skype and Overgrive. The Skype tray icon continues being loaded correctly.

I've tried with the following workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/1056242/476500 but it didn't work and even my Skype tray icon disappeared.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the default desktop.
Thanks.