# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS has missing icons for system apps such as "Software Updater" and "Calculator"

Tags: gnome, 18.04, icons

fist time-long time here. This is actually the first issue I've had where I couldn't resolve it through questions that have already been asked on these forums.

So, I noticed my issue after upgrading last night from 18.04 to 18.04.1. I freshly installed 18.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad E485, using the minimal installation as I couldn't get 18.04.1 to install - the GRUB menu was as far as I got.

Now, since the upgrade, I have noticed some system icons are generic placeholders [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Ad8.png)

The affected apps are:

Calculator, Input Method, Language Import, software Updater, System Monitor and Terminal (the terminal you see on my dock is separate download of LXTerm).

I have attempted 2 fixes from the askubuntu forums [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769034/xubuntu-16-04-all-icons-disappeared-after-update) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056226/ubuntu-budgie-18-04-lts-system-tray-icons-not-all-showing), (the latter took a LONG time to complete and didn't help) I tried a new icon pack (masalla) found [here](https://www.deviantart.com/users/outgoing?https://github.com/hayderctee/masalla-icon-theme/releases/download/0.8-2/masalla-icon-theme_0.8-2.deb) and nothing changed, I've also sudo apt-get update-ed till my fingers bled.

As you can see, not all my system apps are affected and all of my separately downloaded apps have their icons.

All icons in file manager and on my desktop pointing to things such as the trash and Home folders are also iconless as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiA59.png)

I do have some GNOME extensions running, but none which do anything to icons aside from the Dash to Dock, which I disabled as a test.

Extensions are:

- [Bing Wallpaper Changer][6]
- [Clock Override][7]
- [Dash to Dock][8]
- [Extension Update Notifier][9]
- [Full Battery Indicator][10]
- [OpenWeather][11]
- [Pixel Saver][12]
- [Removable Drive Menu][13]
- [Simple Net Speed][14]

What should I do?

Thanks so much for any help you can provide, please let me know if you need the output of any commands - I've used Ubuntu a reasonable amount a few years ago, but it has been a little while, so forgive me if I'm a little rusty!

Regards,

The Gent

Answer (score 0):

I've been installing various software throughout the day and it appears as though all icons except for "System Monitor" now have been fixed.

I have no idea how but directly after installing Stacer, they all popped back one-by-one as I clicked on them.

Regards,

The Gent