# Ubuntu Budgie: Why is my system tray / app indicator empty?

Tags: indicator, system-tray, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I recently switched from Kubuntu to Ubuntu Budgie. First I installed Ubuntu Mate (ubuntu-mate-sektop), and a couple of weeks later Ubuntu Budgie (ubuntu-budgie-desktop) on top of that. All installs were done using apt.

So far I really like Budgie: the looks, the speed, the window management possibilities... But there is one major problem: Although I have several apps installed that should show up (Zoom, PCloud, FlameShot, among others) the app tray remains stubbornly empty.

When I add the "AppIndicator Applet" to the bottom panel (which is the only panel I have), which seem to be the recommended one, nothing shows up:
[image: screenshot of settings and bottom panel]

When I remove that and add the "System Tray" applet instead, then only the network icon is shown:
[image: screenshot of settings and bottom panel]

It's probable that the successive installations of different Ubuntu flavors messed up some configuration, as it does not seem to be a common problem and searching the web only turned up old or unrelated posts. I am lost and not sure how to start troubleshooting this. Any hint will be appreciated (which config files to look at, logs to watch...).

Comment: did you try to increase/change the panel size?

Comment: @Andra the only size setting I can find is the (bottom) panel height, and changing it doesn't change what icons are shown in the tray. I can't find any way to change the tray's size itself, I'm assuming it will just grow as icons are added ?

Comment: did you see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056226/ubuntu-budgie-18-04-lts-system-tray-icons-not-all-showing ?